# Is “are” a borrowed word?

Tags: etymology, old-english, be, german, old-norse

I read somewhere that English is the only language to have borrowed a form of its *to be* verb from another language. I want to say, if memory serves, that it was *are* that was borrowed from an early Scandinavian language. Is that so?

I know Old English had *sind* for one of their <s>pronouns</s> inflections of *be*, the same as in German.  But did it switch to *are* naturally from some other gentler evolution, or was it borrowed?

Comment: Have you done any research on this yourself?

Comment: No but ['they' came from Old Norse](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=they&searchmode=none)

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=sind

Comment: How could you identify an English word that *isn't* "borrowed"?

Answer (score 7):

The verb *be* has a complex history, being a hodgepodge porridge of three entirely different original verbs, with some forms of one lost to [suppletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) by forms of another.  Another familiar verb with suppletive forms is *go* and *went*, where the past of *wend* replaced that of *go*.

Back to *be*.

The singular *am* had two competing plurals, one of which  *earon, aron* was cognate to  Old Norse *eru*, and the other was *sind* as in German. The German-looking form was replaced by more regular-looking inflections of *be* itself like *ben* and even *best* and *beth*. The *are* forms like *aron, aren, arn, are* survived only in the north, but gradually spread south.  For a time at the birth of what we today call Modern English, both competing forms were found.

All this and much more is explained in the OED’s etymology entry for ***be*** (verb), an extremely small excerpt of which I enclose below.

> An irregular and defective verb, the full conjugation of which in modern Eng. is effected by a
>   union of the surviving inflexions of three originally distinct and independent verbs, viz.
>
> 1. the original Aryan
>      substantive verb with stem *es-*, Skr. *as-*, *’s-*, Gr. ’εσ-, L. *es-*, *’s-*, OTeut.
>      **es-*, *’s-*;
> 2. the verb with stem *wes-*, Skr. *vas-* to remain, OTeut. *wes-*, Gothic
>      *wis-an* to remain, stay, continue to be, OS., OE., OHG. *wesan*, OFris. *wes-a*, ONor. *ver-a*;
> 3. the stem *beu-* Skr. *bhū-*, *bhaw-*, Gr. φυ-, L. *fu-*, OTeut. **beu-*, *beo-*, OE.
>      *béo-n* to become, come to be.
>
> Of the stem *es-*, OE. (like the oldest extant Teutonic) possessed only the
>   present tenses, Indicative and Subjunctive (orig. Optative), all the other parts being supplied from the stem
>   *wes-*, pa. t. *was*, which, though still a distinct and complete vb. in Gothic, was in OE. only supplemental
>   to *es-*, the two constituting the substantive verb *am-was.  Béon, be*, was still in OE. a distinct verb
>   (having all the present, but no past tenses) meaning to ‘become, come to be’, and thus often serving as a future tense
>   to *am-was*.  By the beginning of the 13th c., the Infinitive and Participle, Imperative, and pres. Subjunctive of
>   *am-was*, became successively obsolete, the corresponding parts of *be* taking their place, so that the whole
>   verb *am-was-be* is now commonly called from its infinitive, ‘the verb *to be*,’ although *be* is no part
>   of the substantive verb originally, but only a later accretion replacing original parts now lost.
>
> In OE. the present
>   Indic. of *am* had two forms of the plural, (1) *sind*, *sindon* (= Goth. and Ger. *sind*, L.
>   *sunt*, Skr. *sánti*) and *earon*, *aron* (= ONor. *eru*), the latter confined to the Anglian
>   dialects, where it was used side by side with *sind*, *-un*.  Of these, *sind*, *-on* ceased to be
>   used before 1250, its place being taken in southern Eng. by the corresponding inflexions of *be*.  We, ye, they
>   *beth*, *ben*, *be*, were the standard forms in southern and midl. Eng. for centuries; and even in the
>   sing., *be*, *beest*, *beth* began to encroach on *am*, *art*, *is*, and are now the
>   regular forms in southern dialect speech.  Meanwhile *aron*, *aren*, *arn*, *are*, survived in the
>   north, and gradually spread south, till early in 16th c. *are* made its appearance in standard Eng., where it was
>   regularly used by Tindale.  *Be* continued in concurrent use till the end of the century (see Shakspere, and Bible
>   of 1611), and still occurs as a poetic archaism, as well as in certain traditional expressions and familiar quotations
>   of 16th c. origin, as ‘the powers that be.’  But the regular modern Eng. plural is *are*, which now tends to oust
>   *be* even from the subjunctive.  Southern and eastern dialect speech retains *be* both in singular and plural,
>   as ‘I be a going,’ ‘we be ready.’

Perhaps you were thinking we borrowed *are* from Old Norse, but in fact, it was only a cognate.  On the other hand, just possibly the Nordic invasions and settlements may perhaps have influenced the continued use of the *are* forms.

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: Additional note to the OED quote: their ‘Aryan’ and ‘Teutonic’ mean ‘(Proto-)Indo-European’ and ‘Germanic’, respectively. I can only assume that this etymological article was written quite a long time ago and not update, because both these terms are quite archaic and dated now—‘Aryan’ especially so because it now (on the rare occasion it is used) refers to the Indo-Iranian branch of the Indo-European language family, rather than the family as a whole.